# how to restore soft delete with one more column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

I have a table named data and I am using soft delete to delete the record.i have one more field in my data table which is also updated when a record is deleted. but when I restore that soft deleted record, it updates my deleted_at field but doesn't update the other field.
I use this code

```
Data::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can manually set `deleted_at` to `null` and that field to value, like update. And than save that.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an observer that hooks into the `restored` event:

```php
 <?php

namespace App\Observers;

class DataObserver
{
    public function restored($data)
    {
        // Update field here
    }

}
```

And of course register it a `boot()` method of a service provider:

```php
Data::observe(DataObserver::class);
```

Note: Depending on the timing, you may prefer the `restoring` event instead

Answer (score 0):

```
Data::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore();
```

meant this only for restoring which is set the deleted_at column to null
so if you want update the other field, just do the usual things for updating fields after you restore it

like this one

```
Data::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore();
Data::find($id)->update($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can create function in your **Data** model which will do that for you.

```
public function restoreItem()
{
    $this->deleted_at = null;
    $this->other_field = null;
    $this->save();
}
```

Now you need to call this in your controller:-

```
Data::withTrashed()->find($id)->restoreItem();
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
Data::withTrashed()->whereId($id)->update([
    'deleted_at'=>null,
    'other_column'=>$value,
]);
```